# Lead function group by in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I want to group by lead function by two column. Here is my table data.

```
 Id  Name_Id  Name   Item_Id    Item_Name         date
 1      1      Car       1          SUV        1-Jan-2015
 2      1      Car       1          SUV        12-March-2015
 3      1      Car       1          SUV        20-April-2015
 4      1      Car       2          Sport      23-April-2015
 5      2      Bike      1          SUV        18-July-2015
 6      2      Bike      1          SUV        20-Aug-2015
 7      2      Bike      2          Sport      18-Sept-2015
 8      2      Bike      3          Honda      20-OCT-2015
```

And I need result from above table like.

```
 Id  Name_Id  Name   Item_Id    Item_Name       start date     end date
 1      1      Car       1          SUV        1-Jan-2015      20-April-2015
 2      1      Car       2          Sport      20-April-2015   23-April-2015
 3      2      Bike      1          SUV        18-July-2015    20-Aug-2015
 4      2      Bike      2          Sport      20-Aug-2015     18-Sept-2015
 5      2      Bike      3          Honda      18-Sept-2015    20-OCT-2015
```

Any suggestion really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use `LEAD` here.  The CTE below computes, for each `Item_Id`, the earliest and latest date.  This is then joined to your original table to restrict to records corresponding to the *earliest* `Item_Id`.  At the same time, the end date is also pulled in during the join.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Name,
           Item_Id,
           MIN(date) AS start_date,
           MAX(date) AS end_date
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Name, Item_Id
)
SELECT t1.Id, t1.Name_Id, t1.Name, t1.Item_Id, t1.Item_Name,
       t2.start_date,
       t2.end_date
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.Item_Id = t2.Item_Id AND
       t1.Name    = t2.Name AND
       t1.date    = t2.start_date
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want data which is group by Name_Id & Item_Id. I updated the the question can you please check.

Comment: @John Answer updated, all I did was modify the `GROUP BY` in the CTE, and then slightly modify the join in the query to use name and item.